# IRedmail working good, but can't receive mail just from one sender domain?

Tags: postfix, email-server

After receiving a complaint about not receiving mail from an specific sender, while another user account on the same IRedmail server does, I took a look at mail.log and see the following:

```
Sep  2 03:15:10 mail postfix/smtpd[22517]: warning: xxx.xxx.xx.xxx: hostname xxxxx.xxxxxx.com verification failed: Name or service not known

Sep  2 03:15:11 mail postfix/smtpd[22517]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[xxx.xxx.xx.xxx]: 550 5.1.1 <xxxxx@company.com>: Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table; from=<xxxxx@xxxxx.org> to=<xxxx@company.com> proto=ESMTP helo=<mail.xxxx.cn>
```

The other users on this IRedmail server can receive mail from that sender.

Some idea of what is happening with Postfix here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
User unknown in local recipient table
```

postfix doesn't know anything about a user. Have you created a user?